# react native signing for [AppName]Tests require a development team ios

Tags: ios, react-native, code-signing

I have exported the react native project to ios, and I have already selected the building team profile in project setting of general as :

[image]

[image]

It seems the compiling is ok, but at last, when it should be signing, there is error Popup

[image]

Note that its' the [AppName]Tests that have a signing issue, not the [AppName] it self, what should I do?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

No idea how the "restart" fixed anything for anyone.

If anyone else is having this problem, you need to expand the sidebar:

[image]

Comment: Should get more upvotes because this answer actually fixes the problem, avoiding the "Mystery fix; restarting solved my problem!" - Thank you for pointing out the sidebar.

Comment: This is the real answer

Answer (score 14):

I just try to restart the Xcode and things seems ok now, weird though :D

Answer (score 2):

I had this exact issue. I restarted Xcode many times and it didn't fix it.

Restarting my computer, however, fixed it.

Comment: This fixed it for me. Thank you!

Comment: I hate mystery fixes

Comment: same here - restarting fixed it. weird.